# Accepted papers in conferences with links to pdf's

Tags: feature-request

Can we have a page with accepted papers in top conferences with links to pdf versions online. I am not sure if this is allowed in this forum. I posted this as it is of interest to many people to find links to pdf's before the conference versions are out. Currently there is no webpage to do this(Except Shiva Kintali maintains for few).

Comment: For most of the big conferences someone does end up doing this on their blog. Not sure if this is the right place for such lists.

Comment: I agree. I don't see how we can do this here.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a place for posting arbitrary TCS-related information.

Comment: There are at least a dozen "top" conferences that fall into the TCS ambit, and they typically have over 40 papers each.  I'd prefer to read blogs covering these.

Comment: One could, on the other hand, have a Wiki associated with CSTheory.org which would collect information like this. CSTheory.org could then be more than just a Q&A site, it could be a place where TCS researchers go for all their needs. (The Q&A site and Wiki would be hosted separately, but would link to each other.)

Comment: @Robin: like [this](http://theorymatters.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php)?